# Rust consider specifying the type argument in the function call: `::<T>`

Tags: rust

I simply want to call [this function](https://docs.rs/imageproc/0.22.0/imageproc/contours/fn.find_contours_with_threshold.html) from `imageproc` crate. Right now i'm doing it like this:

`let mut contours = find_contours_with_threshold(&src_image.to_luma8(), 10);`

And i keep getting this error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:77:24
   |
77 |     let mut contours = find_contours_with_threshold(&src_image.to_luma8(), 10);
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the function `find_contours_with_threshold`
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: Num`
note: required by a bound in `find_contours_with_threshold`
  --> /home/mike/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/imageproc-0.23.0/src/contours.rs:61:8
   |
61 |     T: Num + NumCast + Copy + PartialEq + Eq,
   |        ^^^ required by this bound in `find_contours_with_threshold`
help: consider specifying the type argument in the function call
   |
77 |     let mut contours = find_contours_with_threshold::<T>(&src_image.to_luma8(), 10);
   |                                                    +++++
```

I understand that rust is not able to figure out what to expect as a result of that function call. In the documentation it should return a `Vec<Contour<T>>` where `T: Num + NumCast + Copy + PartialEq + Eq` but i don't know how to transpose that in my code.

I've tried doing it this way: `let mut contours: Vec<Contour<dyn Num + NumCast + Copy + PartialEq + Eq>> = find_contours_with_threshold(&src_image.to_luma8(), 10);` but i still don't understand what i'm doing so any help would be great.

Is it something like too many values to unpack in python? i should have done something like `let x, y, z = find_contours..()`?

Comment: What happens if you use `let mut contours = find_contours_with_threshold::<i32>(&src_image.to_luma8(), 10);` (or some other appropriate integer type)?  Does that work?  I'm not familiar with that library, but it's asking for the _specific_ type to put in `Contour` not bounds on it.

Comment: @KevinAnderson it does work indeed. Thanks! Shouldn't that specific type be from `Num, NumCast, Copy, PartialEq, Eq`?

Comment: @Mike `Num`, `NumCast`, `Copy`, ... are traits. The bound `T: Num + NumCast + ...` means that the type `T` must have an implementation of these traits. One type that satisfies such a bound is `i32`, however, it's not the only one. The compiler message means that it's not able to infer *which* type you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a type parameter `T`, which has some trait bounds (`Num`, `NumCast`, etc), and it's unconstrained.

Sure, it could be `i32`, but you could also define a custom type:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct MySillyNumber;

impl Num for MySillyNumber {}

// the rest of the required traits
```

and that's just as vaild a type for `T` as `i32`.

You need to tell rustc what `T` is. You can do it in a few ways:

- turbofish: `find_contours_with_threshold::<i32>()`
- explicit type ascription: `let x: Vec<Contour<i32>> = find_contours_with_threshold()`
- passing it to a function:

```rust
fn main() {
  let x = find_contours_with_threshold();
  foo(x);
}

fn foo(x: Vec<Contour<i32>>) {}
```

- or really any other way that gives rustc a concrete type to substitute for `T`.

Note, this is different to using `Vec<Contour<dyn Num + ...>>`. This will turn the elements into "trait objects", which uses dynamic dispatch (with a vtable) to perform runtime polymorphism. This probably isn't what you want, in large part because `dyn Trait` doesn't have a known size, which means it can't appear on the stack without using a pointer of some kind. And while `Vec` is arguably a smart pointer, it requires that the contents have a fixed size, since it relies on this for indexing.

Comment: Thanks @cameron1024 - You phrased it as an answer and with a lot more certainty than I had in my comment.  I appreciate how you expanded on the various typical ways to specify it.  For people coming from C++ (ie: me), putting a template type on a *return value* is a common pattern in Rust, but really odd to me, since the rules for C++ function overloading mean on arguments yes, but not on return types.  Not the same constructs, overloads vs templates, but still, it's a default way my brain works, so this kind of thing trips me up slightly.

Comment: IMO, Rust's type inference is actually a bit of a footgun for people new to the language. It's not obvious why something works in one snippet and not in another, and it can be because of a single function call 100 lines down that provides a concrete type. The language would be unusable without it, but it does provide a form of "action at a distance", which can for sure be confusing